# Checkbox field 'reset' function, on change, uncheck until checked again

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simply '**reset**' a **checkbox field** after a form element has been changed.

```
    $('form').on('change', function(){ // after form elems have been changed
      console.log("Form Has Changed after Rate");

        setTimeout(function() { // relevant area
        $('.gfield_checkbox input').attr('checked', false);  
        }, 2000); // end relevant

    });
```

**I am simply trying to reset it here, uncheck what was currently there; but allow it to be checked again afterwards.** All the current attempts do not allow it to be rechecked or used again.

Comment: The unchecking is probably triggering the on.change again. Thus the loop. Try focusing the event listener to wherever the rate field is, instead of the whole form.

Comment: Thanks; that makes sense but the on change is most important; I've updated my question

Comment: Then you need to find a trigger that will not continually trigger itself.

Comment: Use `prop` instead of `attr` ( `$('.gfield_checkbox input').prop('checked', false);` )

Comment: And why is that @adosan

Comment: @No-Spex Properties reflect element state exactly while html attributes don't. There are some cases when $().attr also changes elements prop but this is quite unreliable (http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck it only if it is checked

```
if($('.gfield_checkbox input').is(":checked")){
  // If it is checked...
  $('.gfield_checkbox input').attr('checked', false);  
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Does not allow reuse of checkbox field.

Comment: You can set a boolean variable and use it as a flag